# Twisted error in server with mqtt client

Tags: twisted

I'm running a Twisted TCP server.  Each protocol instance has an mqtt pub/sub client.  I've reduced the actual production code to the simplest possible form below.  I've stripped out a lot of irrelevant complexity to simplify the bug-finding process.  The server works for multiple client connections and produces the data received from the mqtt client, but after any client connects/disconnects/reconnects a few times I get an exception that I haven't been able to understand or trap.  I'm hoping that Jean-Paul or someone can point me at the error of my ways.

Once the exception occurs, no new clients can connect to the server.  Each new connect attempt produces the exception.

Clients that are already connected continue to receive data ok.

The exception is

```
Unhandled Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/python/log.py", line 73, in callWithContext
    return context.call({ILogContext: newCtx}, func, *args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/python/context.py", line 118, in callWithContext
    return self.currentContext().callWithContext(ctx, func, *args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/python/context.py", line 81, in callWithContext
    return func(*args,**kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/posixbase.py", line 614, in _doReadOrWrite
    why = selectable.doRead()
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/tcp.py", line 1069, in doRead
    transport = self.transport(skt, protocol, addr, self, s, self.reactor)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/tcp.py", line 786, in __init__
    self.startReading()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/abstract.py", line 429, in startReading
    self.reactor.addReader(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/epollreactor.py", line 256, in addReader
    _epoll.EPOLLIN, _epoll.EPOLLOUT)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/epollreactor.py", line 240, in _add
    self._poller.modify(fd, flags)
exceptions.IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

The basic server code is: 
(this example will run and does generate the exception)

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.internet.protocol import Factory
from twisted.protocols import basic
from paho.mqtt import client  # The most recent version of the legacy Mosquitto client
from random import randint

class MsgReceiver(basic.LineReceiver):
    def __init__(self, factory):        # new (factory)
        self.factory = factory          # new (factory)

    def connectionMade(self):
        self.mqClient = self.startMQ()
        if self.mqClient:
            self.factory.clients.append(self)
        else:
            self.transport.loseConnection()

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        pass

    def lineReceived(self, line):
        pass

    def on_message(self, mosq, obj, msg):
        try:
            self.sendLine(msg.payload)
        except Exception, err:
            print(err.message)

    def startMQ(self):
        mqName = "-".join(["myAppName", str(randint(0, 99999))])
        mqClient = client.Client(mqName)

        if mqClient.connect("localhost", 1883, 60) != 0:
            print('Could not connect to mq server')
            return False

        mqClient.on_message = self.on_message

        (success, mid) = mqClient.subscribe("myTopic", 0)
        if success != 0:
            return False

        mqClient.loop_start()
        return mqClient

class MsgReceiverFactory(Factory):
    allow_reuse_address = True

    def __init__(self, clients):
        self.clients = clients

    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        return MsgReceiver(self)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        clients = []
        reactor.listenTCP(43217, MsgReceiverFactory(clients))
        reactor.run()
    except Exception, err:
        print(err.message)
        if reactor.running:
            reactor.stop()
```

A simple client that will induce the error when run twice (the first time it runs fine):
Interesting that if I enable the time.sleep(3) it runs fine and doesn't seem to induce the error

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from __future__ import print_function
import socket
import time

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(("localhost", 43217))
data = s.recv(1024)
print(data)
#time.sleep(3)
s.close()
```

Comment: One thing that I am trying is to wrap the sendLine() call in a reactor.callLater(). i.e. reactor.callLater(0.001, self.sendLine, msg.payload).  This may be helping.  Will advise.  JP: Is this an appropriate use of callLater?

Comment: Any exception like this coming out of the internals of a reactor implementation looks like a bug in the reactor implementation.  Is there a client that goes along with this server so other people can reproduce this bug locally?

Comment: JP: I Added sample client code at end of original post.  The reactor.callLater(0.001, self.sendLine, msg.payload) didn't help.

Comment: I suspect that to duplicate will require incoming messages on the mqtt wire (my system handles about 130 per second)

Comment: The server and client use different ports.  Is this client supposed to connect to this server?  Is some other software required?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo.  Now fixed in question.

Comment: When I run the server and the client all that happens is the server logs a connection refused traceback (ending at "paho/mqtt/client.py", line 710, in reconnect) and the client hangs until I interrupt it.  I don't see the reactor traceback from your question.

Comment: Server code expects there to be a mqtt server (like mosquitto) available on port 1883.  Once logged into the mqtt server, every time a message is received on the specified topic, a callback is made to on_message in my server code.  I imagine that for test purposes, in the absence of a mosquitto server, some external test server could be run.  I'll work on a mosquitto simulator later today.  Sorry for the complexity :-)

Comment: I can't see any simple way to put together a mqtt broker simulator so that may not happen.  I can provide an address for our mqtt server but would need to do so privately, as it carries some proprietary data.  Let me know how if you want me to do that.